# Set up MC Connect before SAP validation?

Tags: marketing-cloud, marketing-cloud-connect, sender-authentication-package

Does the SAP (Sender Authentication Package) absolutely need to be implemented on the platform before the set up of the connexion between Marketing Cloud and Sales Cloud and the installation on MC Connect ?
Can we connect the platforms first and get the SAP integrated after ? Would it have any impact on the connexion or synchronization (in case it takes time from the client side to decide a domaine name and make the configuration on it) ?
I guess there should be no impact, but I prefer having a confirmation

Thanks

Regards

Ludivine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No impact at all.

SAP is only related to your MC content branding, Email sender addresses and Cloud Page URL's. There is no problem configuring Connector first.

Comment: Perfect! thanks a lot!